# Django context Datetime unique date

Tags: django, django-templates, django-filter, django-template-filters, django-context

I have in my model one DateTimeField like this

```
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I want to filter the displayed results in the template by date, but each date only once and the time not at all.

in my views,

```
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context['date'] = Blog.objects.order_by().values('timestamp').distinct()
    return context
```

in my html template:

```
 <form id="filter-form" method="GET" action="">

    <select name="dt" id="date">
        <option value="">Filter by Date</option>
        <option value="">All</option>
        {% for filter in date %}
        <option value={{filter.timestamp|date:"m-d"}}>{{ filter.timestamp|date:"d. F" }}</option> <!-- date:"Y-m-d" -->
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Filter"><p></p>
</form>
```

And later in the views I cach them like this:

```
def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
    querydate= self.request.GET.get('dt')
    start_date = "2020-"+querydate+" 00:00:00"
    end_date = "2020-"+querydate+" 23:59:59"
    print(start_date)
    #return Blog.objects.filter(Q(timestamp__icontains=querydate))
    return Blog.objects.filter(Q(timestamp__lte='start_date',timestamp__gte='end_date'))
```

In my template, I have now displayed the same date several times.

- 18. January
- 18. January
- 18. January

How can I display the date only once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query seems to be the issue here.
You can apply distinct right after query.
Here how it would look

```
Blog.objects.order_by().distinct('timestamp__date').values('timestamp__date')
```

This will convert datetime feild to date and then you can get values out the same.